# How to show the image when I click the particular row of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a music player app in android studio. i have some issue in my application. I want to show the ic_volume_up icon on the particular row where I clicked on the `Recyclerview`.

In this code I inflate the `Fragment` and get the songs name and artist name from the storage and after getting them I further pass them into the `Recyclerview.Adapter` to show them in a list. Now I want to make this more attractive by adding the volume icon in the particular row which was clicked in the `Recyclerview`.

```
public class Songs extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerListener{
    private View view,v;
    private List<SongsPlaylistModel> songList=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private String TAG="MyTag";
    private ImageView imageView;
    public Songs() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
       recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.songs_recyclerview);

       getSongsFromMedia();
       return view;
    }

    public void getSongsFromMedia(){
        Context applicationContext =MainActivity.getContextOfApplication();
        ContentResolver musicResolver=applicationContext.getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            SongsPlaylistModel songsPlaylistModel;
            do {
                songsPlaylistModel=new SongsPlaylistModel();
                songsPlaylistModel.setSongname(musicCursor.getString(titleColumn));
                songsPlaylistModel.setArtistname(musicCursor.getString(artistColumn));
                songList.add(songsPlaylistModel);
                Log.d(TAG,songsPlaylistModel.getArtistname()+" "+songsPlaylistModel.getSongname());

            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        putIntoRecyclerView();
    }
    void putIntoRecyclerView(){
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager manager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerViewAdapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(),songList,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRecyclerClick(int position) {
    }
}
```

Adapter class code is as below

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<SongsPlaylistModel> songsPlaylistModelList;
    private String TAG="MyTag1";
    private ImageView imageView;
    private OnRecyclerListener onRecyclerListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SongsPlaylistModel> songsPlaylistModelList,OnRecyclerListener onRecyclerListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.songsPlaylistModelList = songsPlaylistModelList;
        this.onRecyclerListener=onRecyclerListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_playlist_row_layout,null);
        imageView= view.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        RecyclerViewHolder idiomViewHolder= new RecyclerViewHolder(view,onRecyclerListener);
        return idiomViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int i) {
        SongsPlaylistModel songsPlaylistModel=songsPlaylistModelList.get(i);
        recyclerViewHolder.sname.setText(songsPlaylistModel.getSongname());
        recyclerViewHolder.aname.setText(songsPlaylistModel.getArtistname());
        Log.d(TAG,songsPlaylistModel.getArtistname()+" "+songsPlaylistModel.getSongname());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songsPlaylistModelList.size();
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView sname,aname;
        OnRecyclerListener onRecyclerListener;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,OnRecyclerListener onRecyclerListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.onRecyclerListener=onRecyclerListener;
            sname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
            aname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            onRecyclerListener.onRecyclerClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
    public interface OnRecyclerListener{
        void onRecyclerClick(int position);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/song_artist_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SongName"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ArtistName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/speaker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/song_artist_layout"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.968"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/song_artist_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.727" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/song_artist_layout" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlNRQ.jpg) as you can see the speaker icon on the 3rd row i want this in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to have at most one selected item in your `RecyclerView`. Then you need a field in  `RecyclerViewAdapter` to keep track of the selected item as well as the corresponding setter and getter:

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;

public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
    this.selectedPosition = position;
}

public int getSelectedPosition() {
    return selectedPosition;
}
```

Furthermore, since the `View` with the speaker icon is part of the `RecyclerView`'s rows, it should be managed by the adapter/ the view holder. So let's introduce another `View` in `RecyclerViewHolder`:

```
private View speakerView;

public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,OnRecyclerListener onRecyclerListener){
    super(itemView);
    this.onRecyclerListener=onRecyclerListener;
    // initialize other Views...
    speakerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.speaker);
}
```

In the `Fragment`, you can implement the `OnRecyclerListener` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onRecyclerClick(int position) {
    int oldPosition = recyclerViewAdapter.getSelectedPosition();
    recyclerViewAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
    if(oldPosition >= 0) {
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(oldPosition);
    }
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: macht Blau Hi, hope you are fine. i have encounter a problem in my final year project can you please visit it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578857/firebase-push-notification-is-not-generated-when-app-is-killed-in-android